# What is Azure Cloud Services-L3

Tags: azure, cloud

Today i received a JD which asked to have Azure Cloud Services-L3 experience . I googled it but no success. Has it anything to do with the Cloud Security or Level 3 Experience ? I dont know what Level 3 experience could be or what Level 3 Security can be ?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not relevant to SO for a good question to ask. Ideally, L2, L3 etc., were defined at each company levels based on their experience/band size.

Comment: so What exactly is L2 , L3 . Cant find any documentation for Azure cloud services L3 . What actually is L3 ?

Comment: There is no documentation for this. You need to contact that company and provide the details for this Level of expertise